# Wordpress ajax call is returing the html of the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am getting the data from the sql table and storing the results inside the associative array after that i have encoded into json but the problem is that it is returning the html of the page along with the results

**this is my php code**

```
<?php


add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_loadmore','my_loadmore');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_loadmore','my_loadmore');

function my_loadmore(){

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name="wpnn_tweets";
    $paged=$_POST['page'];
    $page=$paged*10;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name LIMIT 1 OFFSET $page");

    $arr = array();

    foreach($results as $row){ 
    $arr['userScreen']=$row->userScreen;
    $arr['userName']=$row->userName;
    $arr['tweetCreated']=$row->tweetCreated;
    $arr['tweetText']=$row->tweetText;
    $arr['tweetRetweetCt']=$row->tweetRetweetCt;
    $arr['tweetFavoriteCt']=$row->tweetFavoriteCt;
    }  

    echo json_encode($arr);

    wp_die();
}

    ?>
```

**this is how i am retrieving the json in the front end**

```
$ = jQuery;
function scroller() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
            $(this).off("scroll.ajax");
              var page=parseInt($(this).data('page'));
    var ajaxurl=$(this).data('url');  
                 $.ajax({

        url:ajaxurl,
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            page:page,
            action:"my_loadmore"
        },
        error:function(response){
          console.log("error");  
        },
        success:function(data){
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
        }
     });

       }
  }

$(window).on("scroll.ajax", scroller);
```

Comment: Is there perhaps an error message within the returned HTML?

Comment: @PatrickQ there is no error the results are showing but along with the whole html of the page

Comment: So you've actually gone line-by-line through that HTML to make sure that there is no error message _within_ the HTML?

Comment: yes when i have also appended the html in the div

Comment: @PatrickQ I think i have problem with my ajax call when i am just using echo "result" in the ajax.php it is returning the whole page

Comment: Would need to see the HTML to see what the values are for when you make $(this).data('url') or $(this).data('page') calls, and is ajaxurl coming from a wp_localize_script() call? I don't think the WP Ajax mechanism is global by default

Comment: Should also pass the ajax endpoint with wp_localize_script to get the one WP wants. Like `wp_enqueue_script('my_script', 'somescript.js; ...)` then `wp_localize_script('my_script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var ajaxurl = $(this).data('url');`

This returns null unless you explicitly set it in your HTML.  The easiest solution is to replace it with something like the following.

`var ajaxurl = 'my-cool-endpoint';`

This was not the solution to this particular problem, but I feel like it's a good thing to check for others coming to this page with the same problem.  Replace `wp_die()` with `die()`.  [See the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) for more details, but here is the relevant line.

> A call to this function complements the die() PHP function. **The difference is that HTML will be displayed to the user in the case of a typical web request.**

Comment: Well, you shouldn't need to `die()` at all.  Going to echo the statements of the others and suggest you're getting an error page as the response.  Dump your data to the error log (i.e. `error_log($arr)`) and/or open up the error log itself and see what it says.

Comment: `die` at the end is actually recommended by WP - to make sure the call is terminated as soon as the response is sent back. `wp_die(), die(), exit, exit()` all work

Comment: @prieber it is showing me the html of the request sending page in the response

Comment: You may be right, but almost everything Wordpress does and suggests as a good practice is absolutely wrong, including this.  There are no other lines after the `echo`, what are we worried about executing?

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra what is the value of `$(this).data('url');`?

Comment: I think it's because of the hook system, there's not a guarantee that something else won't be running / called

Comment: Per @TayyabGulsherVohra, we need to know what `$(this).data('url')` is. If it's not pointing at the WP Ajax action, that would explain why you're getting HTML back. It should be admin-ajax.php per the `wp_localize_script` call I mentioned in my last comment on the question

Comment: @JDev518 it is giving undefined

Comment: @prieberit is giving undefined

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra it's probably just using the current URL then.  Make sure that gets populated either by setting it in your HTML or by changing it in the js to be something like `var ajaxurl = "my-cool-endpoint"`.

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra Awesome, I'll update my answer.